# Java Reference while adding elements to a list

Tags: java, arraylist, reference, garbage-collection, overhead

first of all thanks for the help.
I'm aware of the Reference passing mechanism of java and I need to read one million of lines (a word + a_list_of_integers each line) from a text file and put them in  some structures that are class attributes, one hashmap and two arraylist.

The problem is that with the code below, written to save memory reusing the list "termine_frequenza", when I try to get and element from the "frequency" arraylist or the "dictionaryMarTD" hashmap, the list that returns is always the last list that I added.
Adding the declaration of the "Arraylist termine_frequenza" into the While obviously solves the problem but I receive a prevedible "GC overhead limit exceeded" error because of multiple declaration (i tried to increase heap o disable it, but GC fills the cpu capacity trying to free memory.

The question is simple: how can I save memory and at the same time have a correct reading? Thanks.

```
        //Class attributes
        private HashMap<String, ArrayList> dictionaryMapTD; 
        private ArrayList<String> words;
        private ArrayList<ArrayList> frequency;          

        //This is the code of a method of the class that reads from a file
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("dictionary.txt")); 
        s = br.readLine(); 

        String[] splitted;
        ArrayList<Integer> termine_frequenza = new ArrayList<>();

        while(s!=null)
        {
            termine_frequenza.clear(); 
            splitted = s.split(" ");
            words.add(splitted[0]);
            for (int i = 1; i < splitted.length; i++) 
            {   
                termine_frequenza.add(Integer.valueOf(splitted[i]));
            }               
            frequency.add(termine_frequenza); 
            dictionaryMapTD.put(splitted[0], termine_frequenza);
            s = br.readLine();
        }
        //END
```

Comment: *I'm aware of the Reference passing mechanism of java*: then you should realize that your code creates a single frequency list, clears it at each iteration, and stores many references to that unique list in the map. You need one new list at each iteration.

Comment: Could you share the size of the text file?

Comment: What is the memory you allocated for your JVM? How did you create your map (you should pass an initial size of 1,500,000 to avoid constant rehashed). Also, if you can't allocate more memory, using an int[] rather than a List<Integer> would spare a lot of memory.

Comment: @JBNizet i know that, infact i said in the post that one simple solution is to declare a new list into the while, but then --> GC overhead. I want to know if there is the possibility to use one "new" and reuse the same list.

Comment: @SanjeevSaha 3,04GB

Comment: @JBNizet I created the map exactly as you said. The JVM has this parameter: - Xmx5096M  - Xms2024M

Answer (score 0):

Change your  XMS/XMX  parameters in your eclips.ini file.
I set it -Xms256m-Xmx7024m  for 3000000
If it has no effect then try to modify that parameters for application
In your eclips go to
 RunConfigurations->Arguments->VM Arguments
for your application and put
-Xms256m
-Xmx7024m

Then in your code move
termine_frequenza = new ArrayList<>();
inside while and remove
termine_frequenza.clear();

GC should not complain 
In my case It runs for 7000000 records

Let me know if it helps